# The recognized python version different from the installed python version

Tags: apt, python, python3

I am pretty new to Ubuntu, so sorry if this question is too basic. I have followed these links to install python 3.7 on my Ubuntu 18.04.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/

https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/#install3-linux

However, once I run the command `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.6.8`. Problem is if I try again to install python 3.7 using the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

I get

```
 python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.4-1+bionic2).
```

`which python` does not give me anything, but `whereis python` yields to

```
 /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/python
```

Does it mean I have all the versions? which I cannot understand, since I have installed only one python on my system.

So any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I have been suggested that this could be a duplicate of [I changed my Python version - but it didn't "take" everywhere?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112461/i-changed-my-python-version-but-it-didnt-take-everywhere) but I think mine is a different problem cause nothing there helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: type `which python` and `whereis python` to see installed python versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I changed my Python version - but it didn't "take" everywhere?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112461/i-changed-my-python-version-but-it-didnt-take-everywhere)

Comment: @cmak.fr it says: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/python
 Does it mean I have all these versions?

Comment: You should have all the versions. Try `python3.7 --version`.  The symlinc for `python3` will stay at 3.6 unless you change it, which isn't necessary. The pythonic thing to do is to use virtual environments.